# Angular:Error :binding ngFor to an array(Invalid Pipe argument)

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

Please note that other questions about the same error didn't help because I'm using different way to get the data.

I want to get JSON data from the API and show them in the page using Angular.My json data consist of array of faq in faqlist.I want to get title and id from every element of the array and show them in the page using ngFor directive.

I have successfully fetched data from API.

I am trying to bind it using ngFor directive but i am getting following error. I have no clue what i am doing wrong if any body could help me that will be helpful. Below is my code and error.

```
                                  **ERROR**
```

[image: ERROR]
                  JSON DATA
[image]

OUTPUT(this.faqq)
[image]

[image]

faq-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { faqService } from "../faq.service";
import { Faq} from "../faq";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Token } from '../token';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-faq-list',
  templateUrl: './faq-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./faq-list.component.css']
})
export class faqListComponent implements OnInit {

  token:Token;
  faqq:Observable<Faq[]>;

  constructor(private faqService: faqService,
    private router: Router) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();

  }

  reloadData() {
    this.faqService.getToken()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.token=new Token(res);

        this.faqService.getfaqList(this.token.access_token)
            .subscribe(res => {
              this.faqq=res.faqList.faq.map((faq:any)=> new Faq(faq));
              console.log(this.faqq);
              debugger;
          })
      })
  }

}
```

faq-list.component.html

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h2>Faq List</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id :</th>
            <th>Title :</th>
            <th>excerpt :</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let faq of faqq |async">
            <td>{{faq.id}}</td>
            <td>{{faq.title}}</td>
            <td>{{faq.excerpt}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

faq.service.ts

```
  getfaqList(token_t:String):Observable<any>{
    let body="";


    let header = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      .set('Accept','application/json')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/xml')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token_t);

    return this.http.post('url',body, {headers: header});
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `pipe` like this:

```
reloadData() {
    this.faqService.getToken()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.token=new Token(res);

        this.faqq = this.faqService.getfaqList(this.token.access_token)
            .pipe(map(res => res.faqList.faq.map((faq: any) => new Faq(faq)) ));
          })
      })
  }
```

The `| async` pipe expects an `Observable`, which is what `pipe()` returns. In your original code you assigned an array to `faqq`, not `Observable` of array.

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked.As I'm a beginner in angular can you please explain what did you do?

Comment: Sure. I added an explanation in my answer. Would appreciate if you could tick my answer. Thanks.